# Transiciones en CSS JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un proyecto web y quiero cambiar de imagen al hacer hover en una lista desplegable. Lo hace pero demasiado rápido.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que sea más despacio este cambio?
Me gustaría que al pasar el mouse por la lista vaya cambiando tanto el texto como la imagen de una forma más agradable y no tan abrupta.
He intentado con transition en el css pero no me ha funcionado.

HTML:

```
 <div>
    <nav class="navegador">
        <ul class="menu-horizontal">
           <li>
               <a href="#">Especialidades</a>
               <ul class="menu-vertical">
                   <li><a href="#" id="implantes" onmouseover="cambioTexto('implantes'); 
return false;">Implantes</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#" id="ddr" onmouseover="cambioTexto('ddr'); return 
false;">Diseño de sonrisa</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#" id="carillas" onmouseover="cambioTexto('carillas'); 
return false;">Carillas</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#" id="dolor" onmouseover="cambioTexto('dolor'); return 
false;">Tratamiento del dolor</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#" id="endo" onmouseover="cambioTexto('endo'); return 
false;">Endodoncias</a></li> 
               </ul>
           </li>
           <li>
               <a href="#">Equipo</a>
               <ul class="menu-vertical">
                   <li><a href="#">Ejemplo 2.1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Ejemplo 2.2</a></li>
                </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Area Cliente</a></li>
        </ul>
       </nav>
 </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="text-box">
            <img src="img/show/dolor.jpg" alt="" id="show-img">
            <h2 id = "titulo-wrapper">Align image an text</h2>
            <p id="show-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. 
      Sunt perferendis porro tenetur nesciunt dicta tempora libero fugiat consectetur 
      nobis accusantium culpa velit ex exercitationem molestias, suscipit rem eligendi 
      doloribus! Ea!</p>    
        </div>
    </div>
```

El CSS de las partes:

```
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 15px auto;
    width: 90%;
    transition-duration: 20s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
#titulo-wrapper{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

#show-img{
    border-radius: 20px;
    max-width: 500px;
    float:left;
    border: 3px solid;
    margin-right: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
   
}

#show-text{
    text-align: justify;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

y por último el JS. Este JS funciona, el problema es que como digo el cambio se hace muy rápido por lo que entiendo que el problema está en el css pero no sé cómo hacerlo:

```
});
let textos = {
    "implantes":{
        texto:"Los implantes devuelven a tu diente toda la funcionalidad y la estética 
         necesaria para no darte cuenta que llevas uno, somos pioneros",
        imagen:"img/show/implante.jpg",
        especialidad:"Implantes"
    },

    "ddr":{
        texto:"El diseño de sonrisa perfeccionado en SmileDental, con la mejor 
        tecnología... tecnologia de punta del siglo 21, moderan",
        imagen:"img/show/sonrisa.jpg",
        especialidad:"Diseño de Sonrisa"
    },

    "carillas":{
        texto:"Las carillas de ayudan a Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur  officia 
        deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
        imagen:"img/show/carillas.jpg",
        especialidad:"Carillas y Estética"
    },
    "dolor":{
        texto:"El dolor es Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed 
        do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim 
       veniam, quis .",
        imagen: "img/show/dolor.jpg",
        especialidad:"Tratamiento del dolor"

    },

    "endo":{
        texto:"la endodoncia es peor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
        ",
        imagen:"img/show/endo.jpg",
        especialidad:"Endondocias"
    }
};
function cambioTexto(idEnlace) {
    let contenido = textos[idEnlace];
    let texto = document.getElementById("show-text");
    let image = document.getElementById("show-img");
    let titulo = document.getElementById("titulo-wrapper");
   
    titulo.innerHTML="<h2 id = 'titulo-wrapper'>"+contenido.especialidad+"</h2>";

    if(image){
        image.src = contenido.imagen;}

    texto.innerHTML="<p id='show-text'>"+contenido.texto+"</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal como está, no es solo cuestión del CSS.

Voy a abordar cuatro cosas, observaciones del CSS, luego por qué no funciona, luego una opción con explicación, y al final un ejemplo funcionando.

**1.** Primero, las duración de la transición se aplicaría en el estilo que vas a modificar, no en el contenedor.

Por ejemplo tienes la duración y características así:

```
.wrapper{
  transition-duration: 20s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;}

#titulo-wrapper{
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2px;}
```

Para simplificar no voy a usar un evento onMouseOver disparado desde tu lista, sino un estilo css hover en el mismo objeto. Tu duración y timing lo mandé al objeto afectado.

```
.wrapper{}
#titulo-wrapper{
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  transition-duration: .5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;}

#titulo-wrapper:hover {
  background-color: #99F;}
```

Acá lo puedes ver funcionando: https://jsfiddle.net/Rafael_/rx3n5qeb/11/

**2.** El detalle es que hasta donde puedo ver, estás disparando eventos no "transicionables" por CSS directo.

Tu JavaScript lo que dispara son cambios de contenido. De un texto hola a un texto adios.

Hola => Adios

Esto no es transicionable por CSS Tendrías que hacer una especie de Morph que no hay en CSS. Lo mismo con un cambio de imagen, la image está o está una diferente.

**3.** Lo que podrías hacer son **transiciones con opacity**. El opacity si puede transicionar de valor 1 totamente opaco, a 0 transparente (pasando por valores flotantes intermedios), y viceversa.

Pero, para que funcione como "transición" lo usarías agregando una animación keyframes.

En este otro ejemplo vas a notar como, aparte del cambio de color del fondo (que no te sirve para tu caso) desaparece el texto por un momento y hay un fade in del nuevo texto.

https://jsfiddle.net/Rafael_/rx3n5qeb/14/

Esto es como queda:

```
@keyframes opacidad {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
  
#titulo-wrapper:hover {
  animation: opacidad 2s;}
```

Otras cosa "transicionables" puede ser el color del texto.

Tendrías que adaptar tu JavaScript, para que aparte de cambiar los valores, agregue un nuevo estilo. Ahorita estoy usando tu id titulo-waper. Prepara un estilo nuevo quiza llamado class="transicion" y asígnalo cada vez que se ejecute tu evento. (Por eso you usé hover en los ejemplos)

Trata con algo así:

```
titulo.classList.add("transicion");
```

P.D. Solo podemos animar el fade-in al inicio del cambio con los @keyframes con CSS, y no un fade-out, ya que no hay manera de saber la duración anticipando el mouseOver del usuario, pero ese fade-in ya suavizará la transición y le dará al usuario una pista visual de que algo ha cambiado.

---

**4. Editado:**

Como en realidad desconozco qué más tiene tu script, acá te dejo una prueba con otro script. Este al hacer hover en el primer **li** asigna el class="transition" al objeto con id="wrapper".

https://jsfiddle.net/Rafael_/rx3n5qeb/23/

Nota que usamos un id="wrapper" y no el class="wrapper", porque el target tiene que ser muy específico.

No es perfecto, es solo un "proof of concept" de asignar la animación, pero te puede servir de base.